# Align left and right same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this problem:

[image]

Basically on the second line "Matricola: XXXXXX" isn't right aligned.

My latex is:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\textsc{Relator}

Prof. NameName\\
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\hfill \textsc{Candidato}

\hfill Name Name\\
\hfill Matricola: XXXXX
\end{minipage}
```

is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use `\hfill` for the alignment, use `\flushleft` and `\flushright`:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushleft
\textsc{Relator}

Prof. NameName\\
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushright
\textsc{Candidato}

Name Name\\
Matricola: XXXXX
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 24):

A `\hfill` that occurs at the start of a line will be ignored. To avoid this, use `\null\hfill` in place of `\hfill`.

Comment: None of the suggestions I found were working until I saw this and tried using the \null before the \hfill. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\null\hfill` somehow didn't work for me. However, `\hglue0.00001pt\hfill` did